# JAVA How to append a list and TableView trought a while in java?

Tags: java, javafx

Iam new into java coding, iam learning and to learn i propose to me create a traceroute program that keep testing the ping response on the route traced.

The first step is get the IP from user and make the traceroute, getting all ip address to be pinged, but iam stuck on this, when i try to add a parsed return of traceroute output to the Jtable, it dont acumullate it, just add the last entry of my while.

Please dont blame my by the bad coding, iam learning.

Iam trying to figure out how to add data to a list and a JTable from a while.

This program get informations from other class, this other class runs a tracert to a ip address and return to Main the tracert results in this format:

13ms;14ms;23ms;192.168.2.3
13ms;14ms;23ms;192.168.2.1
13ms;14ms;23ms;200.122.222.22

this is my table fields: ping1,ping2,ping3,hop

I need to put this data in the table but need to be all ips of the list but iam getting only the last one.

I made alot of tests and commented it because did not workd.

Main.java

```
package application;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import application.Main.Pinge;
import application.NetworkDiagnostics;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {

            // Layout
            FlowPane noRaiz = new FlowPane();
            // Cena
            Scene minhaCena = new Scene(noRaiz, 400, 500);

            // Nós
            TextField ip = new TextField();

            // Tables
    //  List lista = new ArrayList<String>();       
    //  lista.add("1;2;3;4");
//      List<Pinge> lista = Arrays.asList();
    //  List<Pinge> lista = Arrays.asList(
    //          new Pinge("OK","OK","OK","OK")
    //          );

        TableView<Pinge> tabela = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn colunahop = new TableColumn<>("Hop");
        TableColumn colunaping1 = new TableColumn<>("Ping1");
        TableColumn colunaping2 = new TableColumn<>("Ping2");
        TableColumn colunaping3 = new TableColumn<>("Ping3");

        colunahop.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("hop"));
        colunaping1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("ping1"));
        colunaping2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("ping2"));
        colunaping3.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("ping3"));

        tabela.getColumns().addAll(colunahop, colunaping1, colunaping2, colunaping3);


        Button vai = new Button();
        vai.setText("vai");

        Label texto = new Label();
        texto.setText("");

        TextArea resultadow = new TextArea();

        // Adicionar elementos na cena
        noRaiz.getChildren().add(ip);
        noRaiz.getChildren().add(vai);
        noRaiz.getChildren().add(texto);
        noRaiz.getChildren().add(tabela);
    //  noRaiz.getChildren().add(resultadow);


        vai.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @SuppressWarnings("null")
            @Override

            public void handle(ActionEvent envent) {
                String resultado = new String();
                ip.setText("registro.br");
                vai.setFocusTraversable(true);
                texto.setText("Rastreando: " +  ip.getText());
                resultadow.setText("Rastreando: " +  ip.getText());
                resultado = application.NetworkDiagnostics.traceRoute(ip.getText());
        //      tabela.getItems().add(lista);
                String[] result = resultado.split("\n");
                String payload = null;
            //  lista.add(resultado);
                int x1 = 0;

            //  lista.add(lista.lastIndexOf(lista)+1, new Pinge("TESTE","TESTE","TESTE","TESTE"));
                List<Pinge> lista = null;
                while (x1 < result.length) {
                    System.out.println(x1 + ": " + result[x1]);
                    String[] result1 = result[x1].split(";");
                //  payload = payload + result1[3] + ":" + result1[0] + ":" + result1[1] + ":" + result1[2] + "\n";
                    lista = Arrays.asList(new Pinge(result1[3],result1[0],result1[1],result1[2]));
                //  lista.add(new Pinge(result1[3],result1[0],result1[1],result1[2]));
                    resultadow.appendText(result1[3] + ":" + result1[0] + ":" + result1[1] + ":" + result1[2] + "\n");

                //resultadow.setText(result[x1]);   
                x1++;
                }

                //List<Pinge> lista = Arrays.asList(new Pinge("TESTE","TESTE","TESTE","TESTE"));
                tabela.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(lista));
            }
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(minhaCena);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


public static class Pinge {

    private String hop;
    private String ping1;
    private String ping2;
    private String ping3;

    public Pinge(String hop, String ping1, String ping2, String ping3) {
        this.hop = hop;
        this.ping1 = ping1;
        this.ping2 = ping2;
        this.ping3 = ping3; 
        }

    public String getHop() {
        return hop;
    }

    public void setHop(String hop) {
        this.hop = hop;
    }

public String getPing1() {
    return ping1;
}

public void setPing1(String ping1) {
    this.ping1 = ping1;
}

public String getPing2() {
    return ping2;
}

public void setPing2(String ping2) {
    this.ping2 = ping2;
}

public String getPing3() {
    return ping3;
}

 public void setPing3(String ping3) {
     this.ping3 = ping3;
 }
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

This is the class where do the tracert command

NetworkDiagnostics.java

```
package application;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import application.Main;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class NetworkDiagnostics {


static String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
    java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
    return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
}

private final String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();

public static String traceRoute(String string) {
    String route = "";
    String res = "";
    int ms = 0;
    File arquivo = new File("c:/pedro/tracert.log");

    try {
        Process traceRt;
        traceRt = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tracert " + string);

        // read the output from the command
        route = convertStreamToString(traceRt.getInputStream());
        route = route.trim().replaceAll("    ", " ").replaceAll("  ", " ").replaceAll(" ms", "ms").replaceAll(" ", ",");
        String[] split = route.trim().split("\n");

        //regex ip and domain
        String IPADDRESS_PATTERN = "(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)";
        String DOMAIN_PATTERN = "^(www\\.|)(([a-zA-Z0-9])+\\.){1,4}[a-z]+$";
        Pattern patternIP = Pattern.compile(IPADDRESS_PATTERN);
    //  Pattern patternDo = Pattern.compile(DOMAIN_PATTERN);

        int x = 1;

        while (x < split.length) {
            // debug
            System.out.println(split[x]);
            int y = 0;
            String[] details = split[x].split(",");
            while (y < details.length) {
                Matcher matcherIP = patternIP.matcher(details[y]);
            //  Matcher matcherDO = patternDo.matcher(details[y]);
                if (details[y].contains("ms"))
                {
                    res = res + details[y] + ";";
                }
                if (matcherIP.find()) {
                        res = res + matcherIP.group() + "\n";
                    }

                y++;
            }

            x++;
        }

        convertStreamToString(traceRt.getErrorStream());

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

    try {

        if (!arquivo.exists()) {
            // cria um arquivo (vazio)
            arquivo.createNewFile();
        }

        // caso seja um diretório, é possível listar seus arquivos e diretórios
        File[] arquivos = arquivo.listFiles();

        // escreve no arquivo
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(arquivo, true);

        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        bw.write(route.replaceAll("\\s", " "));

        bw.newLine();

        bw.close();
        fw.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return res;
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Read the information about [mcve] and post one that demonstrates the issue you have. The posted code and inforamtion is way too long TMHO.

Comment: JTable is a Swing component. You are using JavaFX. Tags have been updated.

Comment: you re-create the list inside the while loop (that one in the eventhandler), that's why you get only the last entry. Instead, create the list before the while and add items inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks for looking kleopatra. But the declaration of the list is inside the eventhandler and before the while. since list.add not working how can i add itens inside the loop? thanks!